# Are there shortcuts for text editors/processors to delete the rest of a line?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, text-editors, text-editing

The cursor may stay in the middle of the line and there may be necessity to delete whatever stands from the right side of the cursor, but only till the end of current line. I don't know how this called properly and if there is such function in text editors, but if there is such, what shortcut usually used for this?
I'm mostly interested in Notepad++.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there is but it's not really a shortcut. For pretty much all GUI-based editors, you can hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>, hit <kbd>End</kbd> and then hit <kbd>Delete</kbd>. This is no different from just manually selecting the text with the mouse and deleting it.

Comment: Different text editors will have different commands for this.  Good ones will let you assign the function to whatever key you prefer.  In my editor, I've assigned it to Shift-End.

Comment: Practically, all programmer's editors do this. It may not be assigned by default but you can assign your own keyboard combination to it. And also to delete from cursor position to the start of the line.

Comment: If you want to give Vim a go (yes, its available on Windows) then you can do all sorts of things, much more powerful than Notepad++ (in terms of ability out of the box) but there is a fairly steep learning curve. With vim its as easy as hitting `Escape` (to go out of Insert mode into Normal mode) and then doing `d$`. I imagine there are bindable shortcuts for GUI editors too but if you give Vim a go I have a feeling you'll want to stick with it :)

Comment: TECO, built in about 1963, had a one key command for that.  What was more complicated was deleting the entire line.

Comment: If I remember correctly, there are several ways to do this in vim. `d$` as QuickishFM mentioned will delete (`d`) from the cursor to the end of the line (`$`). However, I believe `D` will delete the entire line, starting at the cursor and ending at the end of the line. So, that's a 1-key command when in normal mode, which is what vim users are in most of the time.

Comment: Since this question is not exclusive to Notepad++, I cannot resist the need to butt in: in Emacs, it's <ctrl-k> as standard. [Finally a question where I can do my username justice.]

Comment: @WalterMitty deleting an entire line in vim is only one extra stroke (dd vs D).

Comment: IIRC,  delete the entire line in TECO might have been 0LK$$.  0L moves to the beginning of the line,  and K kills the rest of the line, which is now all of the line.  My memory is unreliable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Delete to end of line

In Notepad++ it is the following shortcut:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd>  Delete to end of
> line

Source: [Notepad++ Keyboard Shortcuts - Virendra's Techtalk](https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/notepad-keyboard-shortcuts/)

Comment: Since you've asked "why not use the built-in Notepad++ shortcut" on a few other answers, I'll offer a couple of reasons: (1) the built-in shortcut is only slightly quicker than *shift+end, delete*, (2) using the universal one means your muscle-memory will be applicable in almost every other application, (3) the universal method can be more fine-tuned e.g. *shift+end+left, delete* to delete to almost the end of the line

Comment: @Hannu no, turned out it also works in GEdit and Mousepad.

Comment: Works in plain Notepad too

Answer (score 34):

"Delete to end of line"

**Windows**, try this:
Hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and hit <kbd>End</kbd> (selects the text) then <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

**Linux**, some editors mimick (i.e. 'works' the same as) windows editors, "native editors" (especially those running in shell/terminal) e.g. nano (pico) usually differ:
First press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to split the line, creating a new line with the end part of the previous, then hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and hit <kbd>k</kbd> to **k**ill the line.

Answer (score 33):

In Vim, `D` in normal mode will delete to the end of the current line.

Comment: For those who care, so will `d$`, though that's one more keystroke.

Comment: @CGCampbell I'm using a Vi emulator so it may have some differences but my vimrc file allows `nnoremap` where n is (presumably) normal mode and when in eg visual mode you can execute a command as if you were in normal mode using `:normal <myCommand>`

Comment: @CGCampbell I think "plain old vi on Linux" has always been vim. The original Vi was always encumbered software. `:help` in Vim will list various mode names, including Normal mode (which indeed is called [Command mode](https://docs.freebsd.org/44doc/usd/13.viref/paper.pdf) in Vi; that paper is the closest version I can find quickly to the original Vi reference manual.

Comment: I've removed my comments as I was wrong to point out what I did. The standard 6 modes in vim are: Normal, Insert, Replace, Visual, Visual-block and Command-line, so this a fine answer.

Answer (score 7):

I can highly recommend Emacs-keybindings. It takes some getting used to, but it's worth it: you never have to move your hands aways from the main keyboard block (letters and numbers) which is very ergonomical: Moving your hands back and forth plays a major role in carpal tunnel's.

Another upside is that a subset of Emacs keybindings are default in bash.

Emacs keybindings are available for example in Eclipse or Visual Studio Code via plugins.

Anyway, deleting the rest of the line in Emacs is:
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>

Answer (score 6):

It's easy and will work in most visual text editor. Just place the cursor from where text needs to be deleted, then press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>END</kbd>, release pressed keys, then hit <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>. From the cursor to the end of line is deleted.

To erase the whole remaining part of document after cursor, press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>END</kbd>, release pressed keys, then hit <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

I use Windows on a MacBook (there is no end key) and this is what works for me.

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Right arrow</kbd>, release pressed keys, then hit <kbd>DELETE</kbd>.

This selects everything to the right of the cursor and then delete removes it.

Comment: You can `Fn+Right` for the 'End' key

Answer (score 4):

Let's make this Retrocomputing. WordStar - we're talking at least back to 1983 (classic WordStar 3.3):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> then hit <kbd>Y</kbd>.

In other words, this is not a new feature.

I still use WordStar keystrokes in VEDIT. Old habits (yes, back to the 1980s) die hard.

Answer (score 0):

[CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/cudatext/) editor (free) has command named "Delete to line end". Hotkey is Ctrl+K. Hotkey is customizable of course.

[image: CudaText+]

Comment: Ctrl-k comes from Emacs (and possibly Teco)

Comment: @Jason, I remember little of TECO, but it was all printable ASCII character commands. Looked like line noise for the uninitiated.

Answer (score 0):

**Apple**

Delete to End of Paragraph:  <kbd>Cntl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>

Use `Cntl-K` (sometimes denoted as `^k` ) to delete text to the end of the paragraph (i.e. deletes text to the next newline character).

This works for Apple applications like TextEdit and Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

In emacs (and clones/workalikes) it is ctrl-K (if at the very end of the line, this deletes the line end). emacs has its full extension language, with which you can write really anything and bind it to a shortcut, up to "modes" for working with different file types (languages) and running external commands.

In vi (and it's clones) "D" or "d$" (Omit the quotes! "Delete to end of line", also "delete" d  + "move to end of line" $). vi has a very rich command set with base commands that can be composed, even calling out to operating system commands. Current vi clones (the most likely to be found today, on Linux original vi --closed source-- would be a no-no) sport their own elaborate extension language(s).